# NuGet Restore task fails (not compatible with netcoreapp2.2), but it works in Visual Studio

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build a repository in Azure Pipelines. It builds OK in Visual Studio, but when using Azure Pipelines (with an agent running on a build machine), it fails with the following error:

```
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error

Project MyProject is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2). 
Project MyProject supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
```

How can I fix this?

And here is the yaml build script:

```
pool:
  name: MyBuildServer
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run tests'
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

Comment: The project is .net core or standard? can you share yout build pipeline?

Comment: The project is .net standard 2.0. I can share the build pipeline when I am back at work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> NuGet Restore task fails (not compatible with netcoreapp2.2), but it works in Visual Studio

It seems that the version of nuget used on the Azure pipeline is not the latest version, which may cause the incompatibility issues.

To resolve this issue, you can try to add a NuGet Tool Installer task point it to a Version of `NuGet.exe` to install, which you simply specify the version number of the desired `NuGet.exe` you want to execute in the build.

[image]

Once this have been properly configured, the builds all succeeded using the latest incarnation of .net core.

Besides, if above not resolve your question, you can try to use the dotnet restore task instead of nuget restore task.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant! Adding a NuGetToolInstaller task at the beginning, with checkLatest set to 'true' did the trick.